# PHP CTF: Vulnerabilities in PHP before 2007?

Tags: php, ctf

I came across a CTF that i'm trying to solve, the goal is fairly simple: Bypass the authentication form and access the admin-restricted area. You can find the code snippet below.

Things to consider:

1. The CTF is a simulation and a demonstration for a very old PHP bug **(before year 2007)**, meaning the code running in the server is slighlty different from the one given.
2. A hint *(not verified)* one of the functions is vulnerable in **PHP 5.1**

How can I bypass the authentication form?

I read all the changelogs for PHP 4.x and PHP 5.x, and I could not spot any bug that may help me bypass the authentication form. I'm not asking for a working exploit or anything just point me to the right direction as it is an outdated bug and I can't find any resources online at this point.

Comment: OP, I'm smelling a vulnerability with the loose type comparison (!= instead of !==) in the if statement.  If the password is something like 'QNKCDZO', then md5 of this is '0e830400451993494058024219903391' (a so-called 'magic hash') which PHP will treat as the integer 0 with loose type comparison. See https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/blob/master/Type%20Juggling/README.md for more info.

Comment: We won't analyse the code to find a vulnerability. And since your question is about vulnerabilities in PHP itself, the specific code in the CTF is not relevant. So I removed those parts.

Comment: Have you looked up CVEs for PHP?

Comment: This is not a type juggling, nor session related issue. I narrowed down the problem to this: `$x = md5($in); unset($x); // somehow $x must not be unset and $in could be only a string nothing else`. And Yes i looked into the CVE and I could not find an entry for that matter. FYI this CTF is classed extremly hard, and is my last one and I did all of the rest.

Comment: If it's not type juggling, than how else would you get the condition of the `if` statement to evaluate to `false`, so that it doesn't execute `unset($pwd);`?